# "Management Group" field empty in Azure service connection form

Tags: azure-devops, serviceconnection

I have created several Azure service connections in Azure DevOps in the past, but since a few weeks' time, I can't anymore: The "Management Group" dropdown field is empty:

[image: New Azure Service Connection form]

What could the reason be?

Comment: Hi friend, is there any update for this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> What could the reason be?

You should meet these points:

1.Make sure the account you sign in Azure Devops Service is the **same account** you use to sign in Azure Web Portal

2.Make sure you have the access to the ManagementGroups:

[image]

3.Also, you may need to make sure you have corresponding role in the Management Group. Ask your Azure admin to assign you the contributor role to current management group and check that again:

[image]

[image]